# Overlaying a Node on an AreaChart in a StackPane

Tags: java, javafx

I have a stackPane with a chart, and i'm trying to overlay a Label to fit the top of the chart, kind of like a second axis. I've managed to append the overlay to the bottom axes, but I can't figure out how to neatly append it to the top.

[image]

This is the code that achieves the above picture:

```
  private void addBases() {
    final Axis<Number> xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
    final Axis<Number> yAxis = chart.getYAxis();



    //hard code example
    baseNodes.add(new BaseNode(new Label("ATCGTCTGCTACTGACTGCATGCTGACTGACTGACTGAATCGTCTGCTACTGACTGCATGCTGACTGACTGACTGAATCGTCGTGCTA"), yAxis.getLayoutBounds().getMinY(), xAxis.getLayoutBounds().getMinX()));

    }
```

I've tried various combinations of `getMaxX()` and `getMaxY()`, but they seem to make the node disappear. (I assume it's out of the bounds of the window).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AreaChartSample extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        stage.setTitle("Area Chart Sample");
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(1, 31, 1);
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final AreaChart<Number, Number> ac
                = new AreaChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
        ac.setTitle("Temperature Monitoring (in Degrees C)");
        XYChart.Series seriesApril = new XYChart.Series();
        seriesApril.setName("April");
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 4));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 10));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 15));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 8));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 5));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(15, 18));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(18, 15));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(21, 13));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(24, 19));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(27, 21));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(30, 21));

        XYChart.Series seriesMay = new XYChart.Series();
        seriesMay.setName("May");
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 20));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 15));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 13));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 12));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 14));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(15, 18));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(18, 25));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(21, 25));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(24, 23));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(27, 26));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(31, 26));

        ac.getData().addAll(seriesApril, seriesMay);

        Label topLabel = new Label("ATCGTCTGCTACTGACTGCATGCTGACTGACTGACTGAATCGTCTGCTACTGACTGCATGCTGACTGACTGACTGAATCGTCGTGCTA");
        Pane pane = new Pane(topLabel);

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(ac, pane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, 800, 600);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        topLabel.setLayoutX(yAxis.getLayoutBounds().getMaxX() + topLabel.getHeight());
        topLabel.setLayoutY(xAxis.getLayoutBounds().getMaxY() + topLabel.getHeight());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Works amazingly, thanks for taking the time to do that.